# Possible to Stream Video on iphone/iPad Using Windows Encoder?

Tags: iphone, video-streaming

Hello all i use windows encoder to stream video online and have a server that i use to broadcast this stream. i am trying to make an app that streams video to the iPhone/iPad using  a unique link. i have seen apps out that stream their own DVR cameras so there must be a type of converter or encoder to use. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, not at this time. The iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch work natively with the Apple HTTP Adaptive segmented streaming protocols. MMS (Windows Media) streams are not compatible with "i" devices and will not play. You will need to look into encoding your video with this other format. [Check out the Apple specs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for a full description of the protocol. Future versions of Windows Media Services (4.0) are claiming that they will support the Apple protocols but this is only a preview/beta at this time and may not truly support the Apple specs.

If your trying to do on-demand iPhone video, you can utilize a service such as Encoding.com to pre-encode your files in the adaptive segmented format for your users to view. For live encoding, Telestream has a product called Wirecast which can encode in a h.264 Apple approved baseline format which can be sent to a service such as Akamai, Multicast Media, or Wowza Server for distribution to your clients.